# Is there any method to execute "nothing" when certain if condition fails?

Tags: python

In  C programming , when certain condition is satisfied and we need to execute nothing in that case , we simply put a semicolon. Likewise what should be done in case of Python ?

Comment: Just don't specify it. Code that is unwritten cannot be run. Otherwise, use `pass` as a no-op. I'm confused about the problem you're facing

Comment: If you don't actually need to run any code if you pass the if statement, then why write the if statement in the first place? Why not just remove it. It is hard to tell what you need based on your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `pass` statement is what you are looking for:

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass on this question, if not for in Python, an otherwise empty block sole contents is required to be the keyword `pass`:

```
if condition:
    pass
else:
    something
```

This isn't the best, but it sure beats negating the condition and rewriting later as you know that there is some that goes where the pass holds its place.

Answer (score 0):

`pass`

See the tutorial [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm) for details.